# clang support for exceptions on windows xp

Tags: windows, exception, clang

I would like to use clang for c++ development (windows for now but, linux, android etc...), and so far for the past 6 months I was able to compile quite complicated code with little issues. But couple of weeks ago I stumbled on the problem with exceptions not being handled. I researched and read anything i could find but i still don't have definitive answer if it is possible to use exceptions with any combination of mingw/g++/llvm/clang.
The closest leads so far seem to be ruben's builds, but I can't get them to work due to another known problem - strerror_s.

The minimal code i am trying to make work is quite simple:

```
int main()
{
    try { throw 0; }
    catch(...) { return 1; }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated because i have stopped my work and am struggling to get the exceptions going.

Thanks,
Orlin++

Comment: I stepped through the clang code and it seems all needed function calls are emitted (__cxa_allocate_exception, __cxa_throw, __cxa_begin_catch, __cxa_end_catch) but in the generated assembly, i don't see anything after the throw (catch is missing)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you're having trouble with my builds. I must admit Windows XP isn't high on my priority list...

What you can try is to build clang 3.2 yourself using the GCC dw2 toolchain on Windows XP, so that the problematic strerror_s function is not used. This is something that only affects the clang binaries, not any binaries that they produce.

Comment: So this might be the best news so far... Are you saying there is some chance exceptions will work? I actually tried to compile 3.2 earlier but got strerror_s and other similar compilation errors, so I gave up. But now I will try it again. I will link msvcr100.dll. A question: Do I need to compile rt as well? Thanks! If this works it will be great.

Comment: Orlin: with my clang build combined with the GCC 4.6 dw2 build from the same place, exceptions should work fine. The only problem there is that the Clang binary uses strerror_s which is unavailable on Win XP (and apparently Clang assumes it's present on Windows).

Comment: Hi Ruben, i successfully built llvm/clang with i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-dw2-4.6.3-2-release-win32_rubenvb.7z (but I had to link msvcr100.dll). Now when i try to compile my example, i get IO errors related to renaming TempFile: "fatal error: error in backend: IO failure on output stream." I was able to trace it to MoveFileExW, which complains that file is in use by other process. Do you have any ideas? I will keep on debugging for couple more days. Thanks for your help! Orlin++

Comment: @Orlin Hmm, no sorry. I'll see if I can figure anything out about this problem and perhaps get a Clang build out that also works on XP.

Comment: That will be great, or you can give me any pointers, I am determined to keep on trying until i make it work. Thanks, Orlin++

Comment: Ruben: do you have any updates on that? I am willing to help in any way to get this going (financially too). Please let me know what i could do. Thanks again!